# How Does One Recreate Paint Brushes and Other Drawing Tools in Photoshop Accurately?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, pencil

I'm wondering how to recreate a paint brush or any drawing tool in Photoshop. I tried making a brush similar to a paint brush but it didn't turn out right and the stroke doesn't look like a fluid stroke (I already changed the spacing). I tried recreating a pencil, but it doesn't look like a pencil stroke. I saw brushes online that recreate paint brushes and pencils and the strokes made with those brushes look like how it would in real life. I tried playing around with the settings and the brush still doesn't look right. How does one recreate a brush/drawing tool so that it looks accurate?

Answer (score 1):

Many custom brushes you may find are created by using the natural medium (pencil, paintbrush, etc)....

- Make a mark on a sheet of paper
- Scan the sheet and open the scan in Photoshop
- Convert to `Greyscale` and adjust as desired
- Create a marquee selection
- Choose `Edit > Define Brush` from the menu

This creates a brush tip shape the same as the scanned artwork.

You can use any greyscale image to create a brush shape.

It can be very difficult to merely adjust brush settings within Photoshop and achieve some more natural appearances.